# Weird problems with generated html - contents breaking out of divs

Tags: html

I have an HTML page which is completely generated from a Python file. I first created an HTML file and then basically printed everything again from the Python script. Don't ask me why. It's our instructor's requirement. The weird problem is that the contents in the paragraph tags are breaking out of the container if they are too long. It didn't happen in the HTML version though. I've inspected the source code using chrome, and everything seems to be fine.

Can anyone help me out here?

Here's the link to it: http://www.luxuryparadise.co.nr/
This domain name is just a little effort to hide my school domain..

Search for "a" when you opened up the website, and click on the result. It will bring you to a stupid account page. And check on your right where it says recent messages. Click on the little "show more" link to see the problem I'm talking about.

Thanks!

Comment: How is it Python's fault that the HTML is botched?

Comment: I didn't say it's python's fault. I have no idea. I'm 60% sure that it is python's fault...because the pure html version works fine. I actually copied all the code from chrome inspector and pasted it into jsfiddle. And the rendered page doesn't have this problem either... very weird!!!!

Comment: "didn't say it's python's fault, but 60% sure it is python's fault"? Python doesn't know you're generating html. it just sees some text operations. It's not going to "oh, hey, it's this weirdo... I'm going to mess with his head and screw up this facebook app he's working on". Computers may seem malicious some days, but they're not smart enough for that kind of thing yet.

Comment: ok i tell python to generate html by setting the content-type to text/html, that's why python knows about that it's generating html.

Comment: sigh...just this tiny little bug that keeps me from finishing the project...if our instructor finds out that when you put too much text in there it's gonna break, he's gonna go like "well, I might just take a few marks off becuz of that little bug u have there"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's normal. Browsers won't break a massively long 'word' to wrap it to the next line. If there were some spaces in that blob of text, the browser would split them there.

You can try forcing a word break with the CSS3 property:

```
word-wrap: break-word;
```

Incidentally, this has nothing to do with Python. It's purely a client-side display issue.

Comment: I get what you are saying, but how come when I copied all the code from chrome inspector to jsfiddle, everything works fine?

Comment: jsfiddle imposes its own stylesheet as well, and you don't get the exact same environment as on your own site.

Comment: and how come I can't even use jquery plugin on that? I used a text expander plugin on the html site. It collapses long text and adds a "show more". I used that plugin on the whole div, but when I try to use it on any specific paragraph, it fails to work